# Upload and Retrieve Data Class with Image Uri

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

i want to save a data Class in Android Studio Kotlin to firebase.
I now how to save normal data (like Strings) to my RealtimeDatabase, but now i want to also store an Image Uri which is part of my DataClass.

This is how my Data Class looks like:

```
data class ExerciseModel(
var fBid: String = "",
var exercise_name: String = "",
var muscle_group: String = "",
var image: Uri = Uri.EMPTY)
```

I already implemented a function where i can get a image for my imageURI and bind it to a imageView in my App and i also can upload my class without the image with the following function.
A Data Class of the type ExerciseModel is safe to a arraylist called exercises.

```
   override fun create(exercise: ExerciseModel) {

   database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
   val key = database.push().key

    key?.let{
        exercise.fBid = key
        exercises.add(exercise)
        database.child("exercises").child(key).setValue(exercise)

   }

}
```

Now i want to also upload include the image in my Upload to firebase and also retrieve all those Data again. In the following is my function to retrieve all my data once when i start my app.

```
    fun loadExerciseData(){
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("exercises")
    database.get().addOnSuccessListener {
            if(it.exists()){
                for(exerciseSnapshot in it.children){
                    val tempexercise = exerciseSnapshot.getValue(ExerciseModel::class.java)
                    exercises.add(tempexercise!!)
                }
            }

    }
}
```

Can anyone help me to now include the image Uri in uploading and retrieving data from fireBase, please?

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: It does work but i dont include the Image Uri, cause i m not sure how i can implemt this, by using storage

Comment: So right now the code only works if i delete the Image Uri from the Data Class, if i include it it doesnt work, because i think that Realtime Database can't just map an image Uri. But i dont know how to solve it

Answer (score 1):

It will be easier for you if you use a String instead of a Uri.  Firebase knows how to serialize Strings from objects, but it does not know what to do with a Uri.

If you need a Uri object in your application for some reason, you can always convert the String to a Uri using [Uri.parse()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri#parse(java.lang.String)).

Comment: Do i need to use a storage then or can i just change the type to String and keep my code as it is in most parts

Comment: So i changed my image type to string. If i now create an exercise i dont get an error and it shows the image in my RecyclerView. But if i close my app and rerun it, the data ist still shown in my RecyclerView but the image is not. If i then add a new exercise using the SAME picture, it appears then but if i add an exercise using another picture it does not. Which i think means i needs to fine that path to the Image String first before it recognizes it. You have any advice how to solve this?